# Как подключить сеттер к JTextField, собранному в конструкторе GUI Netbeans?

Tags: java, gui, jtextfield

Доброго времени суток уважаемые спецы! Прошу сильно не пинать и объяснить, если можно доходчиво. Проблема: есть Jframe с кнопкой выхода, кнопкой которая считывает из файла .txt пару цифр и вставляет в Jtextfield. По нажатию кнопки не никаких проблем. Я создал поток в другом файле, который считывает те же пару цифр и хочу, чтобы они автоматически вставлялись в Jtextfield в первом файле. Но никак не могу разобраться с сеттерами Jtextfield, а именно куда и как их вставить? Перечитал все, что можно(что нашел) NetBeans все равно ругается и никак не хочет никуда их подключать и вставлять в код запускаемого файла. Если кто может - помогите, так как изучаю Java на дому и кроме как здесь спросить мне не у кого.

```
    package newpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import newpackage.ScanFile;


class EggVoice extends Thread
{
    
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try{
                sleep(5000);        //Приостанавливает поток на 5 секунд
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
            
                                                
                        
            System.out.println("OK!");  
        }
        
    }
}
/**
 *
 * @author Noutbook
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String x="";    //глобальная переменная, которую будет читать второй поток
static EggVoice mAnotherOpinion;  
static ScanFile sf;
/**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
       
        
        
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setText("Text");
        jTextField1.setToolTipText("Text");
        jTextField1.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                jTextField1InputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 151, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
System.exit(0);        // выход
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
try
{
BufferedReader iu = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("lala.txt"));
String ki;
ki = iu.readLine();
iu.close();
x=ki;
System.out.println(x);
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(x));  //пишем х в textfield
//...
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
{
     
    x = ("0");
}       catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

//public void setJtextfield1(ScanFile.result){this.result=result;}     
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

                                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        mAnotherOpinion = new EggVoice();
        mAnotherOpinion.start(); 
        ScanFile sf = new ScanFile();
        sf.start();
        
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

> И второй файл:

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author Noutbook
 */
public class ScanFile extends Thread{
String result="00";
       public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
       public String getResult(){return result;}
   
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try{
                sleep(5000);        //Приостанавливает поток на 5 секунд
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                      
                        
            System.out.println("SCAN!");    
                        
                        
                        try
{
BufferedReader iu = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("lala.txt"));
String ki;
ki = iu.readLine();
iu.close();
                           String x = ki;
                           setResult(x); 
                          
                           //NewJFrame.jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(x));  
System.out.println("x=" + x);
System.out.println("result = "+result);

}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
{
                            //например,сам сделай как надо)
                            String x = "0";
}       catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
        }
        
    }
 
}
```

Comment: //NewJFrame.jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(x));   Вы здесь обращаетесь к филду как к полю класса, хотя они у вас не описаны нигде, похоже вы пропустили очень жирный кусок обучения, перейдя сразу "к вкусному"...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Если бы Вы указали на этот очень жирный кусок обучения, я был бы благодарен!